# System V ABI - AMD64 - Stack alignment in GCC-emitted assembly

Tags: assembly, stack, x86-64, memory-alignment, calling-convention

For the C code below, GCC x86-64 10.2 from [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/T66ses) emits assembly that I pasted further below.

One instruction is `subq $40, %rsp`. The question is, how come subtracting 40 bytes from `%rsp` does not make the stack misaligned?
My understanding is:

- Right before `call foo`, the stack is 16 bytes aligned;
- `call foo` places an 8 bytes return address on the stack, so the stack gets misaligned;
- But `pushq %rbp` at `foo`'s start places another 8 bytes on the stack, so it gets 16 bytes aligned again;
- So the stack is 16 bytes aligned right before `subq $40, %rsp`. As a result, decreasing `%rsp` by 40 bytes must break the alignment?

Obviously, GCC emits valid assembly in terms of keeping the stack aligned, so I must be missing something.

(I tried replacing GCC with CLANG, and CLANG emits `subq $48, %rsp` — just as I'd intuitively expect.)

So, what am I missing in the GCC-generated assembly? How does it keep the stack 16 bytes aligned?

```c
int bar(int i) { return i; }
int foo(int p0, int p1, int p2, int p3, int p4, int p5, int p6) {
    int sum = p0 + p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + p5 + p6;
    return bar(sum);
}
int main() {
    return foo(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
}
```

```x86asm
bar:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        popq    %rbp
        ret
foo:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        subq    $40, %rsp
        movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)
        movl    %esi, -24(%rbp)
        movl    %edx, -28(%rbp)
        movl    %ecx, -32(%rbp)
        movl    %r8d, -36(%rbp)
        movl    %r9d, -40(%rbp)
        movl    -20(%rbp), %edx
        movl    -24(%rbp), %eax
        addl    %eax, %edx
        movl    -28(%rbp), %eax
        addl    %eax, %edx
        movl    -32(%rbp), %eax
        addl    %eax, %edx
        movl    -36(%rbp), %eax
        addl    %eax, %edx
        movl    -40(%rbp), %eax
        addl    %eax, %edx
        movl    16(%rbp), %eax
        addl    %edx, %eax
        movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        movl    %eax, %edi
        call    bar
        leave
        ret
main:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        pushq   $6
        movl    $5, %r9d
        movl    $4, %r8d
        movl    $3, %ecx
        movl    $2, %edx
        movl    $1, %esi
        movl    $0, %edi
        call    foo
        addq    $8, %rsp
        leave
        ret
```

Comment: Interesting find. Apparently the compiler figured `bar` does not require stack alignment so it didn't bother. If you make it `extern int bar(int i);` then the stack will be properly aligned.

Comment: Also if you change `bar` so it does require alignment, for example because it calls another function itself, the compiler notices that too.

Comment: I was curious about this optimization being done at `-O0`. Apparently it is a feature of ipa stack alignment which is the default in GCC. You can turn it on/off with `-fipa-stack-alignment` and `-fno-ipa-stack-alignment` in GCC versions >= 9.0. A comparison of the output with the option on/off in GCC: https://godbolt.org/z/a1YdjG

Comment: Whether the functions can be called from outside ("above") is not really relevant here. The alignment requirement protects function *below* the current one and, since `gcc` can see that all functions below foo have no alignment requirements, it deems it unnecessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose of the 16-byte alignment is so that functions being called at any level *below* the current, don't have to worry about aligning their stack if they require aligned locals.

Without the ABI guarantee, every function that needed this would have to `and` the stack pointer with some value to ensure it's correctly aligned, something like:

```
and %rsp, $0xfffffffffffffff0
```

However, there is *no* reason why this is necessary in this particular case - the `bar()` function is a leaf one, meaning the compiler has *full* knowledge of any alignment requirement at its level or below (it has no locals, and it calls no functions, hence no requirements).

The `foo()` function also has no requirement below, since the only thing it calls is `bar()`. It also appears to be deciding that it's *own* locals do not require that level of alignment either.

Even if `bar()` or `foo()` were called from outside the immediate translation unit (and they *can* be, since they're not marked `static`), that doesn't change the fact that alignment for them is not required.

Things would be different if, for example, `bar` was in a separate translation unit or it called other functions where it couldn't be ascertained that the alignment was not required.

That would mean `gcc` wouldn't have full knowledge of its alignment requirements. And, indeed, if you comment out the `bar` definition line in godbolt (effectively hiding the definition), you will see the line change:

```
// int bar(int i) { return i; }
   --> subq $48, %rsp             ; no longer $40
```

---

As an aside, although the 16-byte alignment is not technically *necessary* in this case, I think it *may* invalidate the claim that `gcc` uses the System V AMD64 ABI. There appears to be nothing in that ABI that allows for this deviation, the text ([PDF](https://uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf)) states (slightly paraphrased, and with my bold):

> The end of the input argument area shall be aligned on a 16 (or 32 if `__m256` is passed on stack) byte boundary. In other words, the value `%rsp + 8` is ***always a multiple of 16 (or 32) when control is transferred to the function entry point.*** The stack pointer `%rsp` always points to the end of the latest allocated stack frame.

There appears to be little leeway in interpreting that in any way that makes the observed behaviour compatible, even though it's known not to cause a problem in this case.

Whether someone considers that important enough to worry about is outside the scope of this answer, I make no judgement on that point :-)

Comment: This inter-procedural optimization goes back at least as far as gcc4.1.  https://godbolt.org/z/66TEne.  `-fno-unit-at-a-time` doesn't disable it.  (My Godbolt link uses `register int` args and `-fomit-frame-pointer` to get *much* simpler asm at `-O0`, and also works at `-O1` with `-fno-inline`.  Also, a 16-byte alignment required operation inside bar() gets the whole chain of callers to follow the ABI, e.g. `volatile __m128 v = _mm_setzero_ps();`

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/Y8ETTa shows that local arrays like `char arr[24]` don't result in callers aligning.  The x86-64 SysV ABI specifies that global *and local* arrays get aligned by 16 if their size is >=16 or variable.  But this case seems to violate that.  Of course, the ABI should really keep its nose out of the internals of functions, and the array ends up aligned for some reason, so no fault on `movaps` in an `asm` statement...   I can repro locally with gcc10.1.0 on Arch Linux with `-fno-stack-protector`, else it aligns with `sub $8, %rsp`.  (I might write an answer later.)

Comment: Ok yes, did finally manage to repro a fault locally with `-O0`, with code and options from https://godbolt.org/z/3MPv7G, because the `-32(%rsp)` that GCC picks happened to work if called directly from main, but not via foo.  Anyway, this doesn't fully count as violating the ABI; it's totally sensible for GCC to ignore that weird and intrusive align-local-arrays point in the ABI.  And I had to use inline-asm to hide the alignment requirement from GCC.  `_Alignas(16)` on the array fixes the problem.

Comment: Making "private" functions is something compilers are already allowed to do, and inter-procedural optimizations are also a known thing.  Slightly optimizing the calling convention is a neat trick, and the important point is that a call from another compilation unit to any of these functions *would* fully respect the x86-64 SysV ABI.  GCC is still "using" the ABI in that sense, not for example passing the first arg in RAX so `bar: ret` would work.  This looks like an application of the as-if rule: what outside observers can't (legally) see can't hurt them.

Comment: Hi @paxdiablo 
So, almost 3 years later, I would just like to take a moment to thank you for this answer. To say it's pure gold would be an understatement.